# how to remove added '?' into url in CI before controller name

Tags: codeigniter

I have a login function where after successful login, new directory mentioned like :

redirect('admin');

But when new directory loaded at that time url become like this :

"//localhost/xyz/?admin"

Here an character "?" added into URL. How can i solve this problem.

Comment: Are query strings enabled in your config? `$config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;`

Comment: function Login()
 { 
   // login code 
    redirect('admin/dashboard');
 }

After that URL become like this : 

//localhost/xyz/?admin/dashboard  

an extra ? character added into url. how can i remove this ?.

Comment: Which URI protocol, in your config, are you using? `$config['uri_protocol']`

Comment: $config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your config (`applications/config/config.php`), [query strings](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html) will be enabled:

```
$config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;
```

To remove the `?`, disable query strings:

```
$config['enable_query_strings'] = FALSE;
```